# Google+ Sign-In done well

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

I'm trying to add Google+ Sign-In to my site. From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/), I know how to do it. However, I am encountering some problems:

The button is not present on page load, and appears shortly after. And once logged in, on every page load, the button appears briefly and is then hidden. This is because the button is created (and also hidden if the user is logged in) via Google's JavaScript. It would be rather distracting for the user. I've come across one solution, which is to use the [custom sign in button feature](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#customizing_the_sign-in_button), which will allow me to serve up the styled button, rather than have it be created after page load. The problem with this is that I just want the default button appearance. It seems rather cumbersome to have to come up with the markup and styling myself in order to get it to look like the default. Also, if they change the default, I'll be left with an outdated button until I notice and fix it. Is there a better way to have the default button be displayed, but also have it not appear / be hidden on page load?

What if my user doesn't have JavaScript enabled (e.g. old mobile phone)? There doesn't appear to be any documentation about a Non-JS implementation. Is it supported? If so, is there any documentation? App Engine's users framework works by just generating a link to a Google sign in page. Is there some way of achieving Google+ sign in like this?

I'm using App Engine. Is it possible to hook Google+ Sign-In into the App Engine users framework? It would be useful to not have to re-write a lot of that functionality.

Lastly, how can you test this locally? Google will reject the request due to the hostname (localhost) not matching the one specified for the key. **Solved:** It turns out that you can add "localhost:8080" (or whatever your dev environment may be) to "JavaScript origins" in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) under "API Access".